# How to disable the spring security login page though there is spring security dependency?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My spring boot version is **2.0.5.RELEASE**.

I have been getting default login page when added the spring security dependency. I don't want to remove the spring security dependency but want to disable this login for certain time. I have tried to add them

```
security.ignored=/**
```

in application.properties file but it is not supporting it. It says that it is deprecated.

I want to add these disabling properties in the application.properties file but not getting the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually add extra configuration, for allow access:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityDisableConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```